# Long / Short press a key?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I would like to do this :
if Ctrl was pressed down for more than 200ms (long press)

It doesn't anything

if the key was pressed down for less than 200ms (short press), send("a")

I got these :

```
~Ctrl:: {
    if KeyWait("Ctrl", "T0.2")
        Send("{Blind}a")
}

; or this :

~Ctrl:: {
KeyWait "Ctrl"
If A_TimeSinceThisHotkey < 200
Send "a"
}
```

both of them do what I want, But when assign any combinision with Ctrl e.g (^x ^c ^z)

for example :

```
^k:: Send("b")
```

and pressing very fast ^k It sends "ba"

- I want when pressing very fast ^k It sends just "b" not "ba"
- when pressing and release RCtrl for less than 200 ms it sends just "a"

[www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=123696](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=82&t=123696)

Any help to solve the problem Please !

Answer (score 0):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

    ~Ctrl:: {
    if KeyWait("Ctrl", "T0.2") AND ( (A_PriorKey = "LControl") OR (A_PriorKey = "RControl") ) 
        Send("{Blind}a")
    KeyWait("Ctrl")
}

^k:: Send("b")
```

See [A_PriorKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Variables.htm#PriorKey)

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue? Giving feedback and sharing knowledge help other users who are searching for similar solutions.